# Is there an unintrusive antivirus program that I can ask to scan object on demand only?

Tags: windows, anti-virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended offline on-demand virus scanners](https://superuser.com/questions/23969/recommended-offline-on-demand-virus-scanners)

I'm looking for an unintrusive antivirus program that I can get to run scans on suspicious objects on demand and only on demand. Most other antivirus programs install many layers of protection and things running in the background and preform regular updates and system scans at inconvenient times.

I want an antivirus program that I can simply right click and object and select "scan for viruses" and nothing more. Is there a reliable antivirus program out there that offers this and only this without the automatic updates, background processes, and intrusive automatic system scans?

Note: this is for Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicates - http://superuser.com/questions/23969/recommended-offline-on-demand-virus-scanners, http://superuser.com/questions/17261/least-disruptive-anti-virus-while-working

Comment: slightly different though, as the OP explicitly asks for a program that doesn't auto-update or perform other background tasks.

Comment: And he doesn't ask specifically for an offline solution...

Comment: Virus Total Uploader does exactly what you want: http://www.virustotal.com/metodos.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without the automatic updates,
>   background processes, and intrusive
>   automatic system scans?

**[ClamWin](http://www.clamwin.com/)** would be what you're looking for, since you want a shell extension.

> ClamWin Free Antivirus does not
>   include an on-access real-time
>   scanner. You need to manually scan a
>   file in order to detect a virus or
>   spyware.

Personally, I prefer **[A-squared Command Line Scanner](http://www.emsisoft.com/en/software/cmd/)**.

Answer (score 2):

[BitDefender Free Edition](http://www.bitdefender.com/PRODUCT-14-en--BitDefender-Free-Edition.html) is an on-demand virus scanner. I don't think it has automatic scans unless you schedule them, but it may have automatic updates -- which can be disabled.

It integrates right into the context menu for easy scanning of certain files:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even if this thread might be closed as duplicate, here is what I recommand:

First of all... Almost every antivirus has that feature. You can try anyone you want but I suggest [Symantec Endpoint Protection](http://www.symantec.com/business/products/family.jsp?familyid=endpointsecurity) and [Kaspersky Antivirus](http://www.kaspersky.com/) v6 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Security Essentials and Malwarebyte - both free